# Proving there is one continuous function $F: X \to [0,3]$ such that $F(x) = n$ if $x\in A_n$ for $n=0,1,2,3.$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

May I please receive feedback on my proof below? Thank you

Suppose $X$ is normal and has closed sets $\{A_0, A_1, A_2, A_3\}$ such that none of the sets $A_i$ is empty and so that $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ if $i\ne j$. Prove there is one continuous function $F: X \to [0,3]$ such that $F(x) = n$ if $x\in A_n$ for $n=0,1,2,3.$ You may assume Urysohn's Lemma has been proven.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Given that $X$ is normal and has closed sets $\{A_0, A_1, A_2, A_3\}$ with none of $A_i$ is empty and $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ if $i\ne j$. Then $A_0 \cap (A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3) = \emptyset$ and $A_1 \cap (A_0 \cup A_2 \cup A_3) = \emptyset$ and $A_3 \cap (A_0 \cup A_1 \cup A_2) = \emptyset$ and $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3, A_0 \cup A_2 \cup A_3, A_0 \cup A_1 \cup A_2$ are non-empty closed sets.

Hence, by Urysohn's lemma, there exists continuous functions $f:X\to [0,1], g: X\to [0,1], h: X\to [0,1]$ such that

- $f[A_0] = \{0\}, f[A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3] = \{1\}$,
- $g[A_1] = \{0\}, g[A_0 \cup A_2 \cup A_3] = \{1\}$,
- $h[A_3]= \{1\}, h[A_0 \cup A_1 \cup A_2] =\{0\}$.

Now, we define $F: X\to [0,3]$ by $F(X) = f(x)(g(x) + h(x) + 1)$ then $F[A_0] = \{0\}, F[A_1] = \{1\}, F[A_2]=\{2\}, F[A_3] =\{3\}$, 
and $F$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that works, though it would be clearer if you explicitly checked the details, not forgetting that you must ensure that $F$ stays in bounds (i.e., that $F(x)\in[0,3]$ for all $x\in X$.

A slightly simpler approach is to choose Urysohn functions $f_1,f_2$, and $f_3$ so that

- $f_1[A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3]=\{1\}$ and $f_1[A_0]=\{0\}$,
- $f_2[A_2\cup A_3]=\{1\}$ and $f_2[A_0\cup A_2\cup A_3]=\{0\}$,
- $f_3[A_3]=\{1\}$ and $f_3[A_0\cup A_1\cup A_2]=\{0\}$

and define $F:X\to[0,3]:x\mapsto f_1(x)+f_2(x)+f_3(x)$. Each $f_k$ takes values in $[0,1]$, so their sum clearly must take values in $[0,3]$, and for $x\in A_k$ we have $f_\ell(x)=1$ iff $\ell\le k$, from which it is immediate that $F[A_k]=\{k\}$ for $k=0,1,2,3$.

Comment: Thank you Brian, your simpler approach is nice

Comment: @brucemcmc: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You have to assume $f,g,h$ values in $[0,1]$ (as you assume Urysohn's lemma, which uses that codomain); then $F$ will map into $[0,3]$. 
And actually do the checks on the final claim:

- $x \in A_0$ implies $f(x)=0$ so $F(x)=0$.
- $x \in A_1$ implies $f(x)= 1, g(x)=0, h(x)=0$, so $F(x)=1(0+0+1)=1$.
- $x \in A_2$ implies $f(x)=1 , g(x) =1, h(x)=0$ so $F(x)=1(0+1+1)=1\cdot 2= 2$.
- $x \in A_3$ implies $f(x)=1, g(x)=1, h(x)=1$ so $F(x)=1(1+1+1)=3$.

Continuity of $F$ follows from the fact that $(u,v,w) \to u(v+w+1)$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^3$, plus an argument on composition and continuity of $x \to (f(x),g(x),h(x))$, of course.

So modulo level of detail and precision, your proof does work.

Comment: Thank you Henno!